# Delete all children in objects array

Tags: javascript, object

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "News",
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "parent": "1",
  "name": "News 2"
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "parent": "3",
  "name": "News",
}, {
  "id": "7",
  "parent": "5",
  "name": "News 2"
}, {
  "id": "15",
  "name": "News 2"
}, {
  "id": "20",
  "name": "News 2"
}];

var deleted_id = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].parent == deleted_id) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  } else continue;
}
```

I need to delete item (e.g. With id: "1"). Also I need to delete all levels children, who has "parent" field the same as id of deleted item.

Pay attention that item with id: 3 - is parent for item with id: 5, and item with id: 5 is parent for item with id: 7. They all - should be deleted as well.

There are some deep levels, therefore, result should be:

```js
[{
  "id": "15",
  "name": "News 2"
}, {
  "id": "20",
  "name": "News 2"
}]
```

Comment: You should check if the parent exists before using it in the compare. Also, you should cache the length of the array, since you change the length in the for loop. The continue statement is also completely redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should find the hierarchy relation. then according to `id` you want to delete go for it's children and delete them with parent.

```js
var arr = [{"id": "1", "name": "News", }, {"id": "3", "parent": "1", "name": "News 2"}, {"id": "5", "parent": "3", "name": "News", }, {"id": "7", "parent": "5", "name": "News 2"}, {"id": "15", "name": "News 2"}, {"id": "20", "name": "News 2"}];

console.clear();

var children = {};
arr.forEach(function (item) {
 if (item.parent)
  children[item.parent] = (children[item.parent] || []).concat(item.id);
});
function deleteItem(id) {
 if (children[id])
  children[id].forEach(deleteItem)
 var index = arr.findIndex(i => i.id === id);
 if (index >= 0)
  arr.splice(index, 1);
}

deleteItem('1')
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/58buvybn/

Here is the code:

```
var arr = [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "News",
        }, {
        "id": "3",
        "parent": "1",
        "name": "News 2"
        }, {
        "id": "5",
        "parent": "3",
        "name": "News",
        }, {
        "id": "7",
        "parent": "5",
        "name": "News 2"
        }, {
        "id": "15",
        "name": "News 2"
        }, {
        "id": "20",
        "name": "News 2"
    }];

    var deleted_id = 1;
    var foundIds = [];
    var findIds = function(delId) {
        var item = arr.find(function(x) { 
            return x.id == delId;
        });

        if (foundIds.indexOf(item.id) === -1) {
            foundIds.push(item.id);            
        }

        var children = arr.filter(function(x) { 
            return x.parent == item.id;
        });

        children.forEach(function(it) {
            findIds(it.id);    
        });
    }
    findIds(deleted_id);
    var newArr = arr.filter(function(x) {
        return foundIds.indexOf(x.id) === -1;
    });
    console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This proposal builds a tree first and the gets an array with the id to delete. Then apply filter and get only the one who are not in the list.

```js
var arr = [{ "id": "1", "name": "News", }, { "id": "3", "parent": "1", "name": "News 2" }, { "id": "5", "parent": "3", "name": "News", }, { "id": "7", "parent": "5", "name": "News 2" }, { "id": "15", "name": "News 2" }, { "id": "20", "name": "News 2" }],
    id = '1',
    idsToDelete = function (data) {
        var tree = {}, ids = {};
        data.forEach(function (a, i) {
            tree[a.id] = { id: a.id, children: tree[a.id] && tree[a.id].children };
            if (a.parent) {
                tree[a.parent] = tree[a.parent] || {};
                tree[a.parent].children = tree[a.parent].children || [];
                tree[a.parent].children.push(tree[a.id]);
            }
        });
        [tree[id]].forEach(function iter(a) {
            ids[a.id] = true;
            a.children && a.children.forEach(iter);
        });
        return ids;
    }(arr);

arr = arr.filter(function (a) { return !idsToDelete[a.id]; });

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work to you I guess.

```js
var arr =  [{  
      id:1,
      name:"News",
   },
   {  
      id:3,
      parent:1,
      name:"News 2"
   },
 {  
      id:"5",
      parent:3,
      name:"News",
   },
   {  
      id:7,
      parent:5,
      name:"News 2"
   },
 {  
      id:15,
      name:"News 2"
   },
 {  
      id:20,
      name:"News 2"
   }];

var deleted_id = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i].hasOwnProperty('parent')) {        
    if (arr[i].parent == deleted_id) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      arr.splice(arr[i].parent, 1);
    }
  } else continue;
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I have only one, first id. And i need delete all children of this id all children on all deep levels.

Answer (score 0):

```
var
    arr = [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "News"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "parent": "1",
        "name": "News 2"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "parent": "3",
        "name": "News"
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "parent": "5",
        "name": "News 2"
    }, {
        "id": "15",
        "name": "News 2"
    }, {
        "id": "20",
        "name": "News 2"
    }];


arr = arr.reduce(function collectItemsBySkippingIds (collector, item) {
    var
        unskippedItemList = collector.unskippedItemList,
        skipItemByIdList  = collector.skipItemByIdList,

        isSkipViaId     = (skipItemByIdList.indexOf(item.id)      >= 0),
        isSkipViaParent = (skipItemByIdList.indexOf(item.parent)  >= 0);

    if (isSkipViaId || isSkipViaParent) {
        if (isSkipViaParent) {
            skipItemByIdList.push(item.id);
        }
    } else {
        unskippedItemList.push(item);
    }
    return collector;

}, {

    unskippedItemList : [],
    skipItemByIdList  : ["1"]

}).unskippedItemList;


console.log("arr : ", arr);
```